# Counting particular values after certain point, across rows of data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

folks -  any help is appreciated;

I have the following rows of values (always 7 values per row) of Excel data (3 examples below), where data is coded as 1 or 2. I am only interested in the 1's.

And so, does anyone know how to; count the times 1 appears in each row, AFTER the first 1 appears.

For example;

2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1. (1 first appears at point 3 in the row, and so how do I count the two  remaining 1's that appear in point 6 and 7?)

2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2. (1 first appears at point 4 in the row, and so how do I count the two remaining 1's that appear in point 5 and 6?)

1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2. (1 first appears at point 1 in the row, and so how do I count the one  remaining 1 that appears at point 6?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `Countif()` to count all 1`s in row then minus 1 from result.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:G1,1)-1
```

[image]